# Cocos2d From iPad to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I currently have an iPad application built entirely on Cocos2D and Chipmunk. I want to port my app to the iPhone now.

All I can find are tips on how to rebuilt your app for the iPad.
Is there a simple solution, like for say, scale down your cocos2D scene?

Does anyone have some best practice tips on this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, CCNode does have a Scale property so you should be able to do something like:

```
if(![MyApp isIPad]){
    [myScene Scale:iPadToiPhoneScale];
}
```

but you shouldn't really do stuff like this (not even sure if it would work).

You should, in your AppDelegate, check if you're running on an iPad or an iPhone and load the correct resources (eg, previously scaled down sprites).

Then, when creating your scenes, instead of positioning your CCNodes in absolute positioning:

```
[back setPosition:ccp(160, 240)];
```

place them in relative positioning:

```
[back setPosition:ccp(0.5*[MyApp deviceWidth], 0.5*[MyApp deviceHeight])];
```

where MyApp would have a bunch of static helpers that would return the device capabilities.

Even better, why not something like:

```
CGPoint convertedPosition = [MyApp convertForDevice:ccp(160, 240)];
[back setPosition:convertedPosition];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sheesh...This is not really an "answer" - but I will say that I had to do this type of conversion once - and one thing that helped me was discovering that you could "change" a XIB file from an "iPhone" to "iPad" one back and forth by editing the XML. I *think* it is a matter of changing:

`archive type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.iPad.XIB"`

to

`<archive type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB"`

(But I don't remember exactly).